# On-topic and off-top subjects

Tags: discussion, off-topic

What subjects are considered to be on-topic and off-topic on Photography.SE? I realise that there is probably a guide somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: See the [help/on-topic] (on topic) and [help/dont-ask] (don't ask) sections on the [help] area of the site.

Answer (score 2):

https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask